# How do I put a border around an image in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `StackPanel` containing five images and I want to put a black border around each image.

The XAML I have at the moment is:

```
<Image Name="imgPic1"
       Width="100"
       Height="75"
       Stretch="Fill"
       VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

I thought I would be just able to put a one-unit margin or padding on the image and set a background color to `000000` but `Padding` and `Background` are both invalid for images.

What is an easy way to do this in XAML? Do I really have to put each image inside another control to get a border around it or is there some other trickery I can use?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Simply wrap the Image in a Border control

```
<Border BorderThickness="1">
    <Image Name="imgPic1"
           Width="100"
           Height="75"
           Stretch="Fill"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Border>
```

You could also provide a style you apply to images that does this if you don't want to do it around every image

---

Final solution from answer and comments added by Pax:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="#FF000000"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image Name="imgPic1"
           Width="100"
           Height="75"
           Stretch="Fill"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: That looks good but how do I make it black? Setting Background affects the space around the border, not the border itself, and there's no Color or Foreground property.

Comment: You have to use the BorderBrush property.  You can specify a hex color there or you can specify a more complex brush.  If you want it to be black it'd be BorderBrush="#FF000000"

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer will not work because of the problem described here 
https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/04/17/279-adding-a-border-around-an-image-control/

I solved it this way.

```
<Viewbox>
    <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red">
     <Image Stretch="None" ></Image>
    </Border>
   </Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 5):

I just stumbled upon this post and the other answer did not work right. Maybe because I now use framework 4 and this post is old?

In any case - if someone will see this by chance in the future - here is my answer:

```
 <Border Name="brdSiteLogo" 
          BorderThickness="2"
          BorderBrush="#FF000000"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="12,112,0,0"
          Height="128" 
          Width="128">

     <Image Name="imgSiteLogo"             
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
         Stretch="Fill"/>

  </Border>
```

The border thickness and brush are important (if you wont choose a color - you will not see the border!!!)

Also, the border should be aligned on your window. The image is "inside" the border, so you can use margins or just stretch it like I did.

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)