# C# WPF Add border to Image on Click event

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, border, selected

I have a C# WPF application. In this application I got a canvas to which I programmatically add images (*Canvas.Children.Add(MyImage)*). (I also have some MouseMove events on the individual images.)

My question is: How can I add an event to the images so I know when they are selected, and also add a border to the currently selected Image.

I've done something similar before with a TextBox:

```
<Canvas.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}"><!-- With TextBox instead of Image, this works -->
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Canvas.Style>
```

But because Image doesn't have a BorderBrush / BorderThickness property, the method above doesn't work. Is there any way to add a border to a selected Image? And also to remove the border again when another Image is selected?

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092992/how-do-i-put-a-border-around-an-image-in-wpf

Comment: `Border bdr = new Border()` then add the image as the child of `bdr` so `bdr.Child = image` for example. Canvas left etc will then go on the border instead of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Border control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

1. Change the TargetType to Border in your XAML.
2. In your code behind add your image to the Child property of a new Border control.
3. Add the border to the Canvas.Children